# Relógio em JavaScript não atualiza

Tags: javascript, html

Estou criando uma view que irá mostrar o horário de um servidor da rede e estou usando JS para obter a data e hora atual do servidor, que por ventura vem a divergir com o horário atual, estando em algumas situações atrasado alguns minutos.

Para exibir um relógio na tela e o manter atualizando-se, usei o script abaixo:

```html
<script>
  setInterval(geraIntervalo, 1000);
  function geraIntervalo() {
      var d = new Date(), displayDate;                              
      document.getElementById("horaServidor").innerHTML = d.toLocaleTimeString('pt-BR');
  }              
</script>

<h3 id="horaServidor"></h3>
```

Porém, se ao declarar e instanciar a variável date passando valores simulando o horário recebido do servidor com hora atrasada, o script não consegue mantém o horário atualizando-se.

Segue exemplo abaixo:

```html
<script>
  setInterval(geraIntervalo, 1000);
  function geraIntervalo() {
      var d = new Date(2019, 01, 30, 03, 14, 15), displayDate;                             
      document.getElementById("horaServidor").innerHTML = d.toLocaleTimeString('pt-BR');
  }              
</script>

<h3 id="horaServidor"></h3>
```

Não entendi o motivo do relógio com horário atrasado ser impedido de manter-se atualizando na tela. Poderiam me ajudar? Busquei algumas perguntas e não tive nada parecido no resultado das minhas buscas feitas.

Obrigado!!

Comment: O `new Date()` vai sempre pegar a data/hora atual do sistema quando a função for chamada pelo intervalo. Ao colocar valores fixos, a data/hora será sempre a mesma.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ao definir valores fixos no objeto `Date()` dentro da função, os valores serão sempre os mesmos. Já o `Date()` sem valores, irá retornar a data atualizada do sistema.

O que você pode fazer é declarar o objeto fora da função, e dentro dela incrementar 1 segundo com o método `.setSeconds()`, mas eu sugiro usar um nome mais específico para a variável e não apenas `d`, já que será uma variável com um escopo global (no caso, eu coloquei `relogio`):

```js
setInterval(geraIntervalo, 1000);
var relogio = new Date(2019, 01, 30, 03, 14, 15), displayDate;
function geraIntervalo() {
   relogio.setSeconds(relogio.getSeconds() + 1);
   document.getElementById("horaServidor").innerHTML = relogio.toLocaleTimeString('pt-BR');
}
```

```html
<h3 id="horaServidor"></h3>
```

Comment: Corretíssimo Sam, não havia pensado desta maneira. Muito obrigado, era exatamente o que eu precisava!!

Comment: @Theotonio, se resolveu o seu problema marque a resposta como correta. Pois assim vai ajudar a quem tem dúvida similar a sua além de possibilitar que outras respostas sejam elaboradas como base no que o Sam respondeu.

Comment: @AugustoVasques Feito! Obrigado Augusto.